# jQuery lightbox 0.5 resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, lightbox

I'm using the lightbox jquery version from http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ - can anyone help me get it to resize dynamicly with viewport when resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

Comment: How would you emplement it, what I want is so pictures never are bigger than viewpoint and when resizing it should resize picture frame too - I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNcUA/)